# moveTo messing up cells outside the range

Tags: google-sheets

im rearranging a spreadsheet using google script. I am first sorting it and then moving some rows within a range to the end of the sheet. Everytime i do the moveTo function some cells that reference the moved rows get changed to reflect the new row numbers even though the cells are outside my range and should not be modified. For example if im moving cell b3 and i have cell f4 =b3 then when i move b3 cell f4 changes to be whatever b3 is now. i tried locking it with =b$3 but still didnt work. Also it messes up the conditional formatting that should be in place for the entire column using something like "d2:e" and it changes to be something like "d2:e109" or something similar. Any clue whats going on?

```
function onEdit(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var allowedSheet = 1;
  if(sheet.getIndex() == allowedSheet) {
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    var sortBy = [1, 3, 2];
    var triggerCol = [1,2,3,10,11,12];
    var rangeStart = "A";
    var rangeEnd = "E";
    var tableRange = "A2:E";

    if(triggerCol.indexOf(editedCell.getColumn()) > -1) { 
      var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
      range.sort([{column: sortBy[0], ascending: true}, {column: sortBy[1], ascending: false}, {column: sortBy[2], ascending: true}]);

      var indexOfIncome = find( sheet, 2, "Income");
      if( indexOfIncome > 0 ){
        var overflowRange = sheet.getRange("A2:E" + (indexOfIncome - 1 ));
        var lastRow = findFirstEmptyCell( sheet, 1 );
        overflowRange.moveTo(sheet.getRange("A" + ( lastRow )));

        var fullRange = sheet.getRange(rangeStart + indexOfIncome + ":" + rangeEnd);
        fullRange.moveTo(sheet.getRange(rangeStart + "2"));
      }
    }
  }
}

function find( sheet, column, value ) {
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getMaxRows()).getValues();
  for( i = 0; i < sheet.getMaxRows(); i++ ){
    if (data[i][0].toString().indexOf(value) > -1 ) {
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

function findFirstEmptyCell ( sheet, column ){
  var data = sheet.getRange( 1, column, sheet.getMaxRows() ).getValues();
  for( i = 0; i < sheet.getMaxRows() ; i++ ){
    if( data[i][0] == "" ){
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an expected behaviour, `moveTo` works just like Cut (Ctrl+X), while your looking for Copy+Paste then delete original content, which should be `copyTo(newRange)` associated with `clear(oldRange)`.

Comment: not sure how youre doing cut and paste but when i do it it does not mess up the rest of my sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using copy and then clearing. Now why in the world google would make a single function that behaves the exact opposite from all the other functions is beyond me. The documentation says moveto behaves as cut and paste but when i cut and paste i do not mess up the rest of my sheet.